# flutter share_plus with firebase link - open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory), null, null, null)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

when i use a firebase-storage link with the share_plus package, this error message comes up:

Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(https:/firebasestorage...: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory), null, null, null)

```
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';

    Future<void> shareImage(String fileURL) async {
        Share.shareFiles([fileURL], text: 'Great picture');
    }
```

Comment: You have to download the file to the device storage before you can share.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the file from Firebase Storage [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/download-files) the Flutter documentation, and then on success you can use your code to share the file.